# Автоматическое скрытие формы

Tags: javascript, html

Привет, разъясните, пожалуйста, новичку такой момент:
Есть форма HTML, в которую пользователем вводятся значения. Есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую запускается функция javascript. При запуске функции форма HTML исчезает, на странице отражается только результат запуска функции.
Как сделать так, чтобы после запуска функции форма HTML не исчезала?

Спасибо.

Comment: Тут экстросенсов мало, скрипт опубликуйте!

Comment: А я хотел уже мысли начать читать а ты @Palmervan все испортил :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

можно с помощью jQuery (ничего сложного). 
Как один из вариантов: форма по нажатию на кнопочку будет скрываться слайдингом. А вообще там много чего.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js">

    $("#id_формы").toggle(true);//по дефолту форма отображается

    $("#id_кнопки").click(function() //по щелчку
    {
        $("#id_формы").slideToggle(1000);//плавно скрыть форму слайдингом вверх
    });
</script>
```

Рекомедую к прочтению  книгу Н.А. Похоренок "jQuery". Это целый справочник, в котором много методов решения подобных задачек.

Comment: Не за что)

Answer (score 3):

Попробую подключить экстрасенсорные способности
Ищи, у тебя в скрипте будет код примерно такого содержания

```
непонятныебуквы.style.display = "none";
```

а может и по другому...но если скрипт не сложный, примерно так будет

Comment: > непонятныебуквы

Зачот)

Comment: Ахаха, поржал +1

Answer (score 3):

Насколько я понял, у вас кнопка типа submit.

Т.е.

```
<input type="sumbit" onclick="javascript: somethingFunc()">
```

Попробуйте лучше

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript: somethingFunc()">
```

или

```
<button onclick="javascript: somethingFunc();">Выполнить функцию</button>
```

Так данные не должны пропадать после нажатия.

Comment: Аа, да, всё верно, submit нужно поменять на button... была у меня такая байда

Comment: Спасибо, совет ценный :)